# Angular render complete event

Tags: angular

What is the best way to capture a completed redraw/render event of an angular component? I want this to occur AFTER every time the component has re-rendered due to some input property changing.

As far as I can see, ngOnChanges fires when any input property changes, but it fires before any subsequent component redraws occurs.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to use the [ngAfterViewChecked()](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview) lifecycle hook:

> Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views / the view that a directive is in.
>
> Called after the ngAfterViewInit() and every subsequent ngAfterContentChecked().

However, this may cause performance issues:

> Notice that Angular frequently calls AfterViewChecked(), often when there are no changes of interest. Write lean hook methods to avoid performance problems.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that hook but was put off by it triggering even though nothing actually had been redrawn. It appears to get triggered when it's parent is redrawn as well. Real shame there is no redraw complete hook in angular.