# How to wait for DOM to render

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have to wait for DOM to render before going into next functions. Here is the flow/lifecycle:

1. Push into the Array:

```
    this.someFormArray.push((this.createForm({
      name: 'Name'
      type: type,
    })))
```

2. Trigger functions that are trying to access HTML from step 3.

```
    this.onSizeChange();
```

3. HTML Renders it:

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of someFormArray.controls">
      <img[src]="someUrl">
   </ng-container>
```

And here is the problem, HTML render should be step 2. but thats not how Angular lifecycle works, to battle this I wrapped step 2. into SetTimeout which naturally triggers after DOM render:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.onSizeChange();
    }, 0);
```

While this works, I'm interested is there any better way to handle this, or this is fine?

**Note:** This whole flow is triggered on user change/click, not onInit, AfterViewInit etc.

Comment: Would be helpful and easier to provide an answer if you can create a minimal demo on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kuofi5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474748/angular-render-complete-event

Comment: @matthelliwell Very different situation

Answer (score 0):

Use the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook which will call a parent function after he rendered properly.

Put the Step #2 inside the afterViewInit lifecycle hook.

https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: This will still not work since `ngAfterViewInit` is called after a component's view has completely initialized. It does not depend on whether the view has fully rendered or not.

Comment: You can put the view in step3 into a separate component(apply *ngIf here) and use the hook in it.

Comment: This isn't the solution since my example code is not initialized onInit, all these functions and the whole flow is triggered on user change/click.

Comment: You can put the onSizeChange in a process.nextTick function.